# Extracting a link id to use within a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, simplemodal

all.

I know this is relatively simple, but my inexperience with javascript is showing. The background is that I'm trying to use SimpleModal with separate modals on the same page. This sort of thing has been explained before (http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/issues/detail?id=32), but I don't understand **this.id** well enough, and the code isn't working.

I don't think my terminology is even correct here, but the *selector* isn't retrieving my link idea properly and parsing it with the "#osx_" string. I realized this (literally hours later) after using an alert.

```
$('a.osx').click(function () {
$('#osx_' + this.id).modal();
});
```

I know I have my HTML set up properly, if I hard code '#osx_newsletter' into both locations it works just fine. That obviously kills the dynamic id that I need.

Here's the code. Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here? I'd *greatly* appreciate it! Thanks!

```
/*
 * SimpleModal OSX Style Modal Dialog
 * http://simplemodal.com
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Eric Martin - http://ericmmartin.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

jQuery(function ($) {
    var OSX = {
        container: null,
        init: function () {
            $("a.osx").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
alert('#osx_'+$(this).attr('id'));
                $('#osx_' + 'donate').modal({
                    overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                    containerId: 'osx-container',
                    closeHTML: null,
                    minHeight: 80,
                    opacity: 65, 
                    position: ['0',],
                    overlayClose: true,
                    onOpen: OSX.open,
                    onClose: OSX.close
                });
            });
        },
        open: function (d) {
            var self = this;
            self.container = d.container[0];
            d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $('#osx_' + 'donate', self.container).show();
                var title = $("#osx-modal-title", self.container);
                title.show();
                d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var h = $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).height()
                            + title.height()
                            + 20; // padding
                        d.container.animate(
                            {height: h}, 
                            200,
                            function () {
                                $("div.close", self.container).show();
                                $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).show();
                            }
                        );
                    }, 300);
                });
            })
        },
        close: function (d) {
            var self = this; // this = SimpleModal object
            d.container.animate(
                {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
                500,
                function () {
                    self.close(); // or $.modal.close();
                }
            );
        }
    };

    OSX.init();

});
```

Comment: Is there any output in the Console ?

Comment: @Mostafa Torbjørn Berg - No errors show up in the console.

Comment: Can you try debug the value of this.id ? is it undefined or is there any other value ??

Comment: Using the alert, this.id comes up as being undefined. 
Using $(this).attr('id'), it correctly identifies and parses with the '#osx_' string, but when I try to use it as the argument in $(argument).modal({}) it doesn't seem to evaluate properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
$('a.osx').click(function () {
    $('[id="osx_' + this.id+'"]').modal();
});
```